# modx /Manager shows only 0

Tags: php, modx

I have received the famous white screen of death before on modx but this is new to me; it is similar to the WSoD but a 0 is written to the page. The manager page used to work and I have not made any changes to the code on the site in quite some time (although someone has modified page content within modx)...

I am using:

PHP Version 5.2.17
MySql Client 5.0.51a
PHP safemode is off.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Could this possibly be something with server memory?

Comment: Does the rest of the site work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have of course dumped the cache, deleted all the files/folders in the core/cache directory etc-etc-etc.

Very odd things can happen in the manager if your php post_max_size is too small, not enough memory [at least 32M] your safe mode is right, register globals is off? The only way I found that out was I was tweaking the php settings and forgot the 'M' after 128, leaving my post size at 128bytes ... not good.

Also - I have solved some unsolvable manager problems by moving the manager folder to a backup [mv manager manager.bak] then "upgrading" to the same version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have deleted the files and folders in core/cache -- phpinfo says I have 64m memory. Do you think upgrading is probably the best bet at this point? There was one time I think clearing some tables fixed the problem but I can't remember which ones (nor can I find on Google)...

Comment: When I used the 'upgrade' trick - I upgraded to the same version. Try that first then if not try upgrading to a newer version. [what version are you using now?]